# Why is my React subcomponent re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

I have this app where I pull a massive amount of data upon page load and then renders a table using react-tables. Each row has a compliance column which contains status labels for if something is compliant or not. This column also contains a button which when pressed updates a state (`queuedPortRecommendations`) with recommended a recommended compliant value.

The table takes a long time to render, as expected when it's around 1400 rows. But what I can't figure out why is why it re-renders when the `addQueuedChange` function is called?

I've tried to remove `addQueuedChange` from the deps array of `useMemo` but then rather than adding a string to the array it replaces it.

I understand if a straight answer is hard to come up with, but any tips or ideas would be appreciated.

#### App.tsx

```
const App = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState<Port[]>([]);
    const [queuedPortRecommendations, setQueuedPortRecommendations] = useState<string[]>([]);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const doFetch = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`${BACKEND_BASE}/api/v1/ports?allData=false`);
        const body: BackendResponse  = await response.json()
        const { ports, portStats } = body.data;
        setData(ports);
      }
      doFetch()
    }, [data]);
  
    const addQueuedChange = (portRecommendation: string) => {
      setQueuedPortRecommendations([...queuedPortRecommendations, portRecommendation]);
    };
  
    const columns = useMemo(
      () => [
        {
          Header: 'Device name',
          accessor: 'device.hostname'
        },
        {
          Header: 'Compliance checks',
          accessor: (port: Port) => {
            return (
              <PortDescriptionRecommendation
                key={`${port.device}-${port.ifName}-port-recommendation`}
                port={port}
                addQueuedChange={addQueuedChange}
              />
            );
          },
        }
      ],
      [addQueuedChange]
    )
  
  return <TableContainer columns={columns} data={data} />;
```

#### PortDescriptionRecommendation

```
const PortDescriptionRecommendation = ({ port, addQueuedChange }: {port: Port, addQueuedChange:  (portRecommendation: string) => void }) => {

  const {remoteHostName, remotePort, tag, type} = port.portRecommendation;
  const remotePortDescription = remotePort ? ` (${remotePort})` : '';

  const handleAddToQueueButtonClicks = () => {
    addQueuedChange(portConfig);
  }

  let portConfig = `
conf t
interface ${port.ifName}
description ${tag}${remoteHostName || ''}${remotePortDescription}
end
wr mem`;

  return (
        <button data-tip={portConfig} className={'btn btn-sm btn-info'} onClick={handleAddToQueueButtonClicks}>
          Add recommendation to list
        </button>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you want to add `useCallback` to `addQueuedChange`, so it wouldn't create new `columns` on each render.

Though it might not solve issue completely:
When `App` component to re-renders. `TableContainer` is also re-rendered. This is default React behavior: when parent is updated, it re-renders all children. To change this behavior you should use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).

In general, when you work with big tables, you want to use `React.memo`. From my experience, I usually memoise rows of the table too.

Make sure that `addQueuedChange` doesn't depend on `portRecommendation`

```
const addQueuedChange = useCallback(
  (portRecommendation: string) => {
    setQueuedPortRecommendations((prevPortRecommendation) => [
      ...prevPortRecommendation,
      portRecommendation,
    ]);
  },
  [setQueuedPortRecommendations]
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used `useCallBack` on `addQueuedChange` and kept `addQueuedChange` as a dep to `useMemo`. Then I wrapped by TableContainer in `React.memo`. It still re-renders everything. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Make sure that `queuedPortRecommendations` are not part of the `addQueuedChange` dependencies array. Use function notation of set state, to remove dependency. In general it's good idea to use function notation of a set state when your next state depends on a previous state.

edit: Moved code into the answer

Comment: Thank you so much, that actually did the trick!!! Now, could you please explain what the difference was here, or point me in the general direction of some documentation pages? As you can tell, I'm quite new to React so it's still a bit confusing for me.

Comment: You had the following sequence of events:

- `addQueuedChange` calls `setQueuedPortRecommendations`
- React re-renders your component with new value of `queuedPortRecommendations`
- `useCallback` check dependencies and detects that `queuedPortRecommendations` has changed and returns new function
- `useMemo` check dependencies and detects that `addQueuedChange` has changed and returns new array with columns
- `TableContainer` get new columns and re-renders

React preserves `setQueuedPortRecommendations`  between renders, so it doesn't trigger updates.

Comment: You should understand what is referential equality, because this is what React relay on to detect changes.

Comment: Thousand thanks for the help and explanation. Got some stuff to read up on now!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `useCallback` to avoid re-rendering, each time you update your app state, a new instance of `addQueuedChange` is created. That's why. And you don't have to add it to the dependencies array.

Comment: I tried useCallback and to remove `addQueuedChange` from the dependency array but then it does not concat the state anymore.

Comment: you need to put your state values into the dependencies array of `useCallback`